# Run Android app in debugging mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-gridview, android-studio-2.3

My Android Studio version is 2.3.3

In my Android app gradle build, I have explictly defined different `server_url` string values for **debug** type and **release** type:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            resValue "string", "server_url", "https://myserver.debug.com/"
        }
        release {
            resValue "string", "server_url", "https://myserver.com/"
            ...
        }
    }
```

In my code, I get the string value by:

```
String url = context.getString(R.string.server_url);
```

I connected my Android phone to my laptop. The Android studio toolbar looks like this:
[image]

I also selected build variants to be "debug":

[image]

I click the [image], the app is running on my phone, however, it uses `server_url` value defined in **release** type. Why?

(Under `build/generated/res/resValues/debug/generated.xml` & `build/generated/res/resValues/release/generated.xml` I see those values, no problem there eihter.)

**==== Update ===**

Adding `defaultPublishConfig 'debug'` fixed the issue (Thanks @Ulug Toprak), but I am still wondering why Android Studio doesn't work without it though I have set Build Variant to "Debug". Maybe a bug in Android Studio?

Comment: Do you try to `clean` the project before run?

Comment: Yes, I tried cleaning the project before running. It doesn't help.

Comment: you can try adding `defaultPublishConfig "debug"` to your build.gradle

Comment: have you added jnidebug ?

Comment: Why don't you use productFlavors?

Comment: glad the work around worked, can you investigate if the `publishNonDefault` in the library build.gradle set the false by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer your updated question,

Multi module setup (application + android library) will not log annotated methods/classes from Android Library Module but will do it on Android Application Module. The reason behind this, is that the Android Gradle Plugin will build all Android Libraries as release versions.

as suggested in the comments adding `defaultPublishConfig "debug"` to the build.gradle file will force the debug version

Comment: Yes, after set `publishNonDefault 'debug'` in the library build.gradle, it works.